# Programmatically check if syncdb is running

Tags: django

I have some signal handlers that work on the Django user. Additionally I'm using South. These signal handlers depends on some migrations that must run in before.

When Django executed snycdb and creates the admin user these migrations haven't run and the signal handlers raise an exception.

I'm searching for a way to detect if Django currently runs syncdb so that the signal handerls can skip execution.

Comment: South has its model and a table where it logs information which migrations has been runed and which was not. Maybe you could use that to check if migrations which you need has been runned?

Comment: This would also be an option. But since the handlers are for post-save  signals on relativly often saved models I would like to avoid a additional roundtrip to the db at this point.

Comment: I think you can safely store that information in global variable and retrieve it only once when application is started.

Answer (score 2):

I trap the DatabaseError exception and check if the ContentType entry for the model I'm trying to use exists, if it doesn't I assume syncdb is happening, otherwise rollback the transaction and re-raise the original exception.  This method incurs in an extra DB access only when DatabaseError is raised.

```
    with transaction.commit_on_success():
        try:
            content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(kwargs['instance'])
            for relation in WorkflowTypeRelation.objects.filter(content_type=content_type):
                workflow_instance = WorkflowInstance.objects.create(content_object=kwargs['instance'],
                    workflow_type=relation.workflow_type)
        except DatabaseError as database_error:
            try:
                ContentType.objects.get(model='workflowtyperelation')
            except ContentType.DoesNotExist:
                # Most probable running during syncdb phase,
                # so ignore the exception
                pass
            except DatabaseError:
                # ContentType model DB table doesn't exists,
                # raise original exception
                raise database_error
            else:
                # The ContentType model exists,
                # there is something wrong with the DB
                # raise original exception
                transaction.rollback()
                raise database_error
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to know if syncdb is running, but there is a way to handle exceptions in python:

Just catch and exception and `pass`:

```
try:
    # code that deals with django user
except ExceptionYouAreGetting:
    # seems like syncdb is running, let's pass for now
    pass
```

Comment: While this is an option I don't want to swallow a `DatabaseError` in the handler because this could also indicate other serious problems.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's not possible to detect whether or not syncdb is running, however, when syncdb or loaddata is running, your signals will receive an extra argument raw.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=ModelA)
def signal_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    raw = kwargs.get('raw', False)
    if not raw:
        <do whatever>
```

This way, you can skip signals to be run when syncdb is being executed.

Comment: The raw argument is only True if the data is being loaded from a fixture. However, some things (like the initial user and the default site) that django creates during the initial syncdb process are not loaded from fixtures, so raw will be False just like in any other save scenario.